# How to instantiate recursive bound generics with inner class in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I would like to have the generic outer class with inner-class as parameter. I was expecting, that I will derive from base class and either use it's inner, or derive inner too. At each level I was expecting to limit inner class usage starting from current level of deriving.

Unfortunately, I meeting various errors and warnings when using the pattern so that I can't imagine, how to use it.

```
package tests.java;

public class Try_GenericInnerRecursion {

    // base class, consisting of outer and inner parts
    public static class Outer1<E extends Outer1<E>.Inner1> {
        public class Inner1 {
        }

        public void addElement(E e) {
            System.out.println("Added " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    // extending outer, but not inner
    public static class Outer2<E extends Outer1<E>.Inner1> extends Outer1<E>{

    }

    // extending both outer and inner
    public static class Outer3<E extends Outer3<E>.Inner3> extends Outer1<E>{
        public class Inner3 extends Inner1 {
        }
    }

    // extending both outer and inner and stopping extension
    public static class Outer4 extends Outer1<Outer4.Inner4> {
        public class Inner4 extends Outer1<Inner4>.Inner1 {
        }
    }



    // instantiating
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Outer1<Outer1.Inner1> a1; // WARNING: Outer1.Inner1 is a raw type

        a1 = new Outer1<Outer1.Inner1>(); // WARNING: Outer1.Inner1 is a raw type

        Outer1<?> a2; // OK 

        a2 = new Outer1<?>(); // ERROR: Cannot instantiate the type Outer1<?>

        Outer1<Outer1<?>.Inner1> a3; // ERROR: Bound mismatch: The type Outer1<?>.Inner1 is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Outer1<E>.Inner1> of the type Outer1<E>

    Outer1<? extends Outer1<?>.Inner1> a4; // OK

    a4 = new Outer1<Outer1.Inner1>(); // ERROR: Type mismatch

            Outer2<Outer1.Inner1> b1; // WARNING: Outer1.Inner1 is a raw type

            b1 = new Outer2<Outer1.Inner1>(); // WARNING: Outer1.Inner1 is a raw type

        // and so on
    }

}
```

How can I use this pattern correctly?

Comment: Extending like `Outer4` is the only way to use such a type (because otherwise parameterizing the type is infinitely recursive). Is there a reason you need such a strict declaration? `E extends Outer1<?>.Inner1` will be a lot less of a headache. How will you use these classes?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can simply do

```
    DerivedCorpus1<?>
```

during wildcard capture, it becomes

```
    DerivedCorpus1<x> where x extends Corpus<x>.Element
```

which is correctly bounded.

In your exmaple

```
    DerivedCorpus1<? extends Corpus<?>.Element>
```

during wildcard capture, it becomes

```
    DerivedCorpus1<x> where x extends Corpus<x>.Element
                        and x extends Corpus<?>.Element
```

apparently, the `extends Corpus<?>.Element` clause is redundant.

Comment: Still can't instantiate class with no errors or warnings.

Answer (score 3):

> `Outer1<Outer1.Inner1> a1; // WARNING: Outer1.Inner1 is a raw type`

Actually, I get "type argument Outer1.Inner1 is not within bounds of type-variable E`".

`Outer1.Inner1` is a raw type, because `Outer1` is a raw type. To use a not-raw type, you would need to write `Outer1<something>.Inner1`. However, that `something` would also have to extend `Outer1<something>.Inner1` in turn. In order to have recursion like this you need a named recursive type. Unfortunately, since `Inner1` is a non-static inner class, it has an implicit reference to an instance of `Outer1`, and so any class that extends it would also need to have an enclosing instance of `Outer1`. `Outer4` and `Inner4` basically do this.

```
Outer4 a1 = new Outer4(); // compiles fine
```

> `a2 = new Outer1<?>(); // ERROR: Cannot instantiate the type Outer1<?>`

You can never do `new something<?>()`.

> `Outer1<Outer1<?>.Inner1> a3; // ERROR: Bound mismatch: The type Outer1<?>.Inner1 is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Outer1<E>.Inner1> of the type Outer1<E>`

This is true. `Outer1<?>.Inner1` is not a subtype of `Outer1<E>.Inner1` -- it's the other way around -- `Outer1<E>.Inner1` is a subtype of `Outer1<?>.Inner1`. This is just like how `ArrayList<?>` is not a subtype of `ArrayList<String>`; it's the other way around.

> `Outer1<? extends Outer1<?>.Inner1> a4; // OK`

This is okay because you have a wildcard at the top level, and your wildcard's bound intersects the type parameter `E`'s bound. In fact, anything that satisfies `E`'s original bound must satisfy this bound, so this bound is useless, and this is the same as `Outer1<?> a2;` above.

> `a4 = new Outer1<Outer1.Inner1>(); // ERROR: Type mismatch`

Doesn't work, for, among other reasons, the same reason that `a1` doesn't work (`Outer1.Inner1` does not satisfy `E`'s bound). It additionally doesn't satisfy your bound (`Outer1<?>.Inner1`) I believe.

> `Outer2<Outer1.Inner1> b1; // WARNING: Outer1.Inner1 is a raw type`

This actually gives the same error as `a1`, for the same reason

Comment: Summarizing your answer you mean that "it is impossible to recursively instantiate class in the case in Java" right?

Comment: But `Outer4` is not generic. I wish to instantiate generics namely.

Answer (score 1):

**Generic specification**

Before I go on to the instantiation problems I revise your generic definition:

```
Outer1<E extends Outer1<E>.Inner1>
```

Outer1 should basically hold elements of type Inner1 or any child classes of it. Therefore the type of the Outer1 object is not of relevance and can be replaced with the following code:

```
Outer1<E extends Outer1<?>.Innter1>
```

Also the extending classes have been slightly modified using the above mentioned.

**Instantiation**

For the instantiation of objects you stated the following:

> ```
> Outer1<Outer1.Inner1> a1;          // WARNING: Outer1.Inner1 is a raw type
> a1 = new Outer1<Outer1.Inner1>();  // WARNING: Outer1.Inner1 is a raw type
> ```

As newacct has already mentioned, `Outer1` is declared with a generic type though you didn't specify any while instantiating the object. The code therefore should be changed to the following one:

```
Outer1<Outer1<?>.Innter1> a1;           // or simply Outer1<?> a1;
a1 = new Outer1<Outer1<?>.Innter1>();   // or simply a1 = new Outer1<>();
```

Similar for assigning classes which extended a base class to a type of that base class.

You specify with the generic type definition what type of elements the instance will hold.

A declaration like

```
Outer1<Outer1<?>.Innter1> test;
```

will accept any instances extending `Outer1` that also match the generic type. This means you can only assign

```
test = new Outer1<Outer1<?>.Inner1>();
test = new Outer2<Outer2<?>.Inner1>();
```

to it, but not `Outer3` or even `Outer4`!

Even if you modify the code further to add f.e.

```
public static class Outer5<E extends Outer1<?>.Inner1> extends Outer1<E>{
    public class Inner5 extends Inner1 {
    }
}
```

you are just able to add

```
test = new Outer5<Outer5<?>.Inner1>();
```

but not

```
test = new Outer5<Outer5<?>.Inner5>(); // FAILS!
```

to something that defined `Inner1` as type argument.

However, there is actually a quite simple solution to this issue. If you define the object like this:

```
Outer1<? extends Outer1<?>.Inner1> test2;
```

you are actually able to do the following things:

```
test2 = new Outer1<Outer1<?>.Inner1>();
test2 = new Outer2<Outer2<?>.Inner1>();
test2 = new Outer3<Outer3<?>.Inner3>();
test2 = new Outer4();
test2 = new Outer5<Outer1<?>.Inner1>();
test2 = new Outer5<Outer5<?>.Inner1>();
test2 = new Outer5<Outer5<?>.Inner5>();
```

as you now explicitly told the compiler that either the `Inner1` type itself or any of its extensions is allowed.

**Code**

I've updated your code and added a couple of new assignments to verify that the changes made actually do not produce any compile errors or warnings except for the `redundant type arguments in new expression` due to explicitly specifying the type arguments instead of using the diamond operator `<>`:

```
public class GenericInnerRecursion
{
    // base class, consisting of outer and inner parts
    public static class Outer1<E extends Outer1<?>.Inner1> {
        public class Inner1 {
        }

        public void addElement(E e) {
            System.out.println("Added " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    // extending outer, but not inner
    public static class Outer2<E extends Outer1<?>.Inner1> extends Outer1<E>{

    }

    // extending both outer and inner
    public static class Outer3<E extends Outer3<?>.Inner3> extends Outer1<E>{
        public class Inner3 extends Inner1 {
        }
    }

    // extending both outer and inner and stopping extension
    public static class Outer4 extends Outer1<Outer4.Inner4> {
        public class Inner4 extends Outer1<Inner4>.Inner1 {
        }
    }

    public static class Outer5<E extends Outer1<?>.Inner1> extends Outer1<E>{
        public class Inner5 extends Inner1 {
        }
    }


    // instantiating
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Outer1<Outer1<?>.Inner1> a1;
        a1 = new Outer1<Outer1<?>.Inner1>();

        Outer1<?> a2;
        a2 = new Outer1<>();

        Outer1<Outer1<?>.Inner1> a3; 

        Outer1<? extends Outer1<?>.Inner1> a4;
        a4 = new Outer1<Outer1<?>.Inner1>();

        Outer2<Outer1<?>.Inner1> b1;
        b1 = new Outer2<Outer1<?>.Inner1>();

        // and so on

        // assigning extension-classes to the parent-class
        Outer1<Outer1<?>.Inner1> c1;
        c1 = new Outer2<Outer2<?>.Inner1>();
        // assigning inner-extension-classes to parent-class
        Outer1<Outer3<?>.Inner3> c2;
        c2 = new Outer3<Outer3<?>.Inner3>();
        // assigning extension class without specified generics to parent class
        Outer1<Outer4.Inner4> c3;
        c3 = new Outer4();

        Outer1<Outer1<?>.Inner1> test;
        test = new Outer1<>();
        test = new Outer2<>();
        test = new Outer5<Outer5<?>.Inner1>();

        Outer1<? extends Outer1<?>.Inner1> test2;
        test2 = new Outer1<Outer1<?>.Inner1>();
        test2 = new Outer2<Outer2<?>.Inner1>();
        test2 = new Outer3<Outer3<?>.Inner3>();
        // new Outer3<Outer3<?>.Inner1>(); not possible as generic type extends Outer3<?>.Inner3 and not Outer1<?>.Inner1!
        test2 = new Outer4();
        test2 = new Outer5<Outer1<?>.Inner1>();
        test2 = new Outer5<Outer5<?>.Inner1>();
        test2 = new Outer5<Outer5<?>.Inner5>();
    }
}
```